# When driving car at 100-120km/h steering wheel starts to vibrate

Tags: ford, steering, vibration, fiesta

I drive a Ford Fiesta which has clocked 110 000km total. When I cross 100-120km/h on a smooth road, the steering wheel starts to vibrate, and the vibration reduces when I reduce my speed. I guessed the problem was in the tires, so I replaced the front tires with new ones, but I still get that vibration at high speeds. I also get these vibrations when I drive at high speed and suddenly slow down towards a bump. Can someone give me an idea for a solution?

Comment: Is there any update to your issue of vibration on steering. I have the same problem with my fista. I have new michelin xm2 energy tyres (driven ~2000kms).

Answer (score 6):

Tires are out of balance, or possible a bent rim. Take it back to where the tires were put on and tell them you have a vibration.

If you have a vibration when you are using the brakes that goes away when you take your foot off the brake you may have warped rotors. I would take car of the tire balance issue first before addressing the rotors. You may only be getting vibration from the tires so you need to fix that first.

Answer (score 3):

The usual culprits are one or more of the following (from most- to least likely):

1. flat spots on tires caused by wheelspin or locking brakes
2. unbalanced rims
3. bent rims
4. (very) cheap tyres
5. worn shock absorbers
6. warped brake rotors
7. worn wheel bearings
8. loose wheelnuts
9. worn suspension bushings
10. loose control arms.

Comment: How old are the tyres? I would add 'tyre belts loosening'. I had a perfectly good vehicle start to vibrate at speed because the tyres were near the end of their life and the internal belts were seperating. A visual check of the tyres will show an undulation across the tread.

Answer (score 0):

Also check your brake disks and pads. If pads were worn they can damage disks and it will cause a vibration

Answer (score 0):

Just had new rims and performance tires installed on a 2001 CLK430.  Same vibration through the steering wheel at 100 kph (ish).....regardless of road surface.....going to get the fronts rebalanced first as they did an alignment and checked the suspension during the install.  I'll post the results.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer that any of the four wheels are out of balance. The lead weights that are put during wheel balancing when the tyres are first mounted tend to fall-off in the course of time. Wheel balancing as well as correct & even tyre pressures in all of the wheels may correct the problem.